# How to call a button using two variables, in C#?

Tags: c#, button, null

On the form there are several buttons all within a panel. What I'm trying to do is enable any of the 64 buttons using 2 predetermined variables. The button I enable is dependent on which button was selected previously. Each button has the name:
"button" + # between 1-9 + letter between A-H. I determine the letter using ASCII values.

> Example: button3A, button 7H, etc.

The code I have crashes and gives me a null value:

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 1)); x = x + 1;
y = (int)listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()[1]; y = y + 2;
DB4.Items.Add("" + x + (char)y);
if ((x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4 || x == 5 || x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7 || x == 8 || x == 9) && (y == 65 || y == 66 || y == 67 || y == 68 || y == 69 || y == 70 || y == 71 || y == 72))
    (this.Controls["button" + x + (char)y] as Button).Enabled = true;
```

Comment: The full exception message as well as where it occurs would be helpful.

Comment: You said all buttons are placed on `panel` but you are searching `button` on **Form's controls**. You need to search **panel's controls**.

Comment: try replacing listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() with listBox1.selecteditem.value

Comment: Crashes *and* gives you a null value? What does that mean?

Comment: I overlooked that, thank you Berkay!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

The problem was that I used this.Controls instead of panel1.Controls. Props to Berklay for noticing such a small detail!